# View Angle plugin missing from Gazebo Garden install

Tags: installation

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm a beginner at Gazebo and I was trying to install Gazebo Garden for Linux (specifically Ubuntu). I can launch the program fine, manipulate the shapes in shapes.sdf, but when I try to use the View Angle plugin I get the following error:

[GUI] [Err] [Plugin.cc:147] Failed to instantiate QML file [:/ViewAngle/ViewAngle.qml].

- file::/ViewAngle/ViewAngle.qml:220:5: IgnSpinBox is not a type

I don't know if this is relevant but ROS installed a version of Gazebo Fortress with ros-humble-desktop-full. I want to use the latest version though so I want to figure out if I can use Garden.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28759/view-angle-plugin-missing-from-gazebo-garden-install/) by [eroc](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/138184/eroc/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2023-02-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I think this is a bug with a fix here: https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/pull/1877

---

Originally posted by [azeey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6889/azeey/) with karma: 704 on 2023-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0